# How to find a document where either one or another field matches a value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model was,

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    first_name : String,
    last_name : String,
    ...
});
```

From this, I need to do search filter option. For that I am passing `name` params with value.

Now I want to return the document  which contains  `first_name == name` or `last_name == name`

How to write the query for that?

Answer (score 7):

```
User.findOne({
    $or: [
        {first_name: name},
        {last_name: name},
    ],
}, function(err, user) {
    ...
})
```

Use `find` if you expect there to be more than one document matching name to be equal to first_name or last_name.

Comment: A text index and an according search might work, too.

Comment: Not sure if it worked for Ranjith, but this approach does work (it did for me). Watch out if need to search for multiple types (like String and ObjectId), since you'll get a Cast Error for ObjectId if you pass it a non-conforming string.